# Can ggplot2 Produce Flowcharts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, flowchart

I would like to draw a simple flowchart in R. As shown in the example below, I would like to be able to determine:

- the shape of the boxes
- the color of the boxes
- the position of the boxes
- the text within the boxes
- the direction of the arrows between the boxes
- the text beside the boxes

[image]

There are several packages, that are able to draw such a flowchart (e.g. [DiagrammeR](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/)). However, **I am wondering if this is possible with ggplot2**, since I would like to use the ggplot2 themes etc.

Comment: First, "*which other package can produce ..."* is almost certainly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Second, I googled `r ggplot2 flowchart` and found quite a few hits: https://scriptsandstatistics.wordpress.com/2017/12/22/how-to-draw-a-consort-flow-diagram-using-r-and-graphviz/ and https://davetang.org/muse/2017/03/31/creating-flowchart-using-r/ to name two. None were perfect. You might also include https://rseek.org/ in your searches, it does a decent job focusing on R-centric results.

Comment: I suggest googling "R plot flowchart" when looking for packages. These types of questions are not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can further extend your search to look for plotting *network graphs*, since a flowchart might be a specialization of one. Check out some of the [examples for `ggnet`](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/), specifically the directed graphs. Again, not perfect, but better than nothing.

Comment: (But don't get me wrong ... I can see value in a package like this, perhaps combining the functionality of `ggnet`, `ggrepel`, and some simple elbow-grease would give you a good start. If I had more time, I might try writing my first "formal `ggplot2` geom function". Care to BountySource it? ;-)

Comment: @ First 2 comments: I am sorry for the bad phrasing. Of cause, you are right that the second question was off topic and therefore I deleted it. However, the real question is, if it is possible to draw such a flow chart with ggplot2. I hope the question gets more clear after rephrasing it.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the ggnet2 link and the other hints! Definitely a good starting point for me.